# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list'

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hi i want to make JSON readable by using loads and dumps, but i encountered this error

```
"TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list'"
```

Here is my code:

```
parsedCoin = json.loads(coin)
print(json.dumps(parsedCoin, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

how i can solve this problem?

Comment: What is `coin`? The error suggests it's a list, not a string which `loads` expects.

Comment: coin is a list.

Comment: how i can decode son.loads(coin) to string

Comment: Where are are you getting the list from? Your code seems to imply that `coin` is supposed to be json already, but that's not possible if it's a list. Is it a list of lines from a json file or something? Give us some more to go on!

Comment: [{'rank': '3', 'symbol': 'ETH', 'market_cap_usd': '102776807996', '24h_volume_usd': '7324680000.0', 'percent_change_7d': '41.8', 'price_btc': '0.0697127', 'percent_change_24h': '10.67', 'id': 'ethereum', 'cached': False, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'last_updated': '1515140950', 'total_supply': '96782123.0', 'percent_change_1h': '-0.97', 'available_supply': '96782123.0', 'max_supply': None, 'price_usd': '1061.94'}]

Comment: coin=[{'rank': '3', 'symbol': 'ETH', 'market_cap_usd': '102776807996', '24h_volume_usd': '7324680000.0', 'percent_change_7d': '41.8', 'price_btc': '0.0697127', 'percent_change_24h': '10.67', 'id': 'ethereum', 'cached': False, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'last_updated': '1515140950', 'total_supply': '96782123.0', 'percent_change_1h': '-0.97', 'available_supply': '96782123.0', 'max_supply': None, 'price_usd': '1061.94'}]

Comment: If that's in your Python code (rather than in a javascript file that you're opening somewhere), then your issue is simply that you don't need to call `loads` at all. You've already got a parsed Python data structure, since you wrote it in Python (there's a lot of overlap in Python and JSON syntax, though there are probably some corner cases where they're not compatible). Just use `coin` instead of `parsedCoin` in your `json.dumps` call and you should be all set.

Comment: You're so good. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

json.loads expects a string. json.dumps(coin) will give you a string version of coin.